# Two papers: Death or Life

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

**Yet another warden**

You are "again" stuck in jail, this time it is bad: You are to be executed tomorrow.
As the warden is always so unprofessional, he offers you a way out in that words:

> Tomorrow, I will present you two folded papers on which I will write "DEATH" and "LIFE" respectively. You will take one of the two and it will determine your fate. Take "DEATH" and you will be executed, take "LIFE" and you are free.

You first think it is a fair game, but your cell mate gives you an unpleasant news:

> He is evil, last time I saw him putting two "DEATH" papers in his hands so you're dead whatever the paper you will choose. Goodbye mate.

**Can you in that desperate situation, once again, save your life?**

**Note**: It is a puzzle I heard in my childhood so I've no source for it. I didn't find this puzzle anywhere in the website, feel free to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed this is duplicate. ☺